# Regex in Terminal to run python

Tags: python, regex, terminal

I have a python file that creates commands to run. My example command is

`mycmd tags add --name email --regex [\\w-\\.]+@([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]{2,4}`

In python file, I'm getting name and regex args using this code.

```
name = self.args.name
regex = self.args.regex
```

I get this error. `zsh: no matches found: [\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]2` How would I get rid of this error and pass regex string?

Answer (score 1):

just enclosed your regex in " " such as
`mycmd tags add --name email --regex "[\\w-\\.]+@([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]{2,4}"`
It works for me on zsh